# File > Open Windows PowerShell shows Unknown file format dialog

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I'm facing issue with the "File > Open Windows PowerShell" for some time, I don't know what to do to solve it, googling also didn't help, and I have installed windows updates many times already.

I use this feature really lot, but now once I click "Open Windows PowerShell" I get an unkown file format dialog (see bellow).

Does anybody know whats wrong? or how I can solve this issue?

[image: File > Open Windows PowerShell]

[image: Unknown file format dialog]

Comment: It looks like that shortcut is pointing to a file named larbi instead of the Powershell.exe. Start with a malware / virus scan and then change the file path to the correct location at C:\Windows\syswow64\Windowspowershell\v1.0

Comment: I'd also have a look at Malware. Have you tried restoring defaults within Change folder and search options?